# MYSQL - Select based on a dynamic value

Tags: mysql, dynamic, varchar

I'm looking for a way to select something in one column based on another column's data. I have 2 tables:

```
input_table - has a column called "year_of_birth"
result_table - has a column called "notes"
```

you see, that "notes" column might contain a year in there, something like "1980". I need to be able to select rows where the notes field contains a match to the year_of_birth field. I have my statement written like this so far:

```
select inp.year_of_birth, res.notes, res.result
from order_input inp join order_result res on inp.order_id = res.order_id 
where res.result !='no match'
and res.notes like '%' + inp.year_of_birth + '%'
```

right now i'm getting an error thta says "conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong because I have a similar statement i'm using that has this type of string in it that works...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) instead of `+`

```
res.notes like CONCAT('%', inp.year_of_birth, '%')
```

Comment: yes `+` will try to add `%` to `inp.year_of_birth`, in the process trying to cast `%` as an integer.  This gives you your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select inp.year_of_birth, res.notes, res.result from order_input as inp join order_resultas res on inp.order_id = res.order_id where res.result <> 'no match' and res.notes like CONCAT('%', inp.year_of_birth, '%')
```